# css button with image as background

Tags: html, css, image, background, background-image

[image: iamge]

CSS

```
#printbutton{
    width: 156px;
    height: 63px;
    background-image: url(../images/Untitled_1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML

`<button onclick="printpage()" class="dontprint" id="printbutton"></button>`

This is my html and css of button image my question is how to get rid of the background beyond the image i am referring to the rectangle behind the image itself my image dont have that background because it looks like [this](http://i248.photobucket.com/albums/gg182/guradio/Untitled.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use background as transparent.

```
button{
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 0;
  border      : 0;
  background  : transparent;
  font-family : inherit;
  font-size   : 1em;
  cursor      : pointer;
}
```

http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-buttons-with-css3/

Answer (score 2):

shape the button as if it is the image add button height and width and border radius

```
button {
border-radius: 46px;
    width: 156px;
    height: 63px;
}
```